# #1111 - Invalid use of group function in case statement mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum, data-retrieval

I want to retrieve due_date from table,I have used following query but it return `invalid use of group function` error .What is wrong with my query?

My Query given below,

```
   select 
sum(
    case when invoices.due_date LIKE '2015-05-10%' 
        then sum(invoice_items.quantity*invoice_items.rate)-sum(IFNULL(payments.amount,0))
    end
    )as 1day, 
sum( 
    case when invoices.due_date LIKE '2015-05-09%' 
        then sum(invoice_items.quantity*invoice_items.rate)-     sum(IFNULL(payments.amount,0))
    end
    )as yesterday 
        from `invoices`
        inner join `invoice_items` on `invoice_items`.`invoice_id` = `invoices`.`id` 
        left join `payments` on `payments`.`invoice_id` = `invoices`.`id` 
        where `invoices`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you want this. I removed your `SUM()` inside the case.

```
select 
sum(
    case when invoices.due_date LIKE '2015-05-10%' 
        then (invoice_items.quantity*invoice_items.rate)-(IFNULL(payments.amount,0))
    end
    )as 1day, 
sum( 
    case when invoices.due_date LIKE '2015-05-09%' 
        then (invoice_items.quantity*invoice_items.rate)-     (IFNULL(payments.amount,0))
    end
    )as yesterday
```

Comment: Thank your for answer.. it seems working fine.. let me go through deeply :)